# How do I find all 2x2 pixel groups in a two color image

Tags: pixel

[image]

I'm working on a project where I am building a map made up of tiles, and I was wondering if there was a way to identify all of these pixel formations inside of an image? Outside of doing it by hand, as it is a very large (3000x1500 pixels) image

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I imagine it might be possible to automate by coding something, but coding is generally off-topic here. Perhaps you could ask on Computer Graphics Stack Exchange or StackOverflow? - however, you'll likely need to have some code/script you have tried already, at least as a starting point.

Comment: This is pretty simple to find programmatically. It's a variation of a problem called "Finding The Number of Islands"